# show single categories all posts in another page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have five different area in my home template where i have created five different post from five category. Every single category, i have 3 post. Now, how will i show single categories all posts in another page ? With html i used a link and named it "show all" . so if i click "`show all`" then i will see all the posts of this category.  How to do it?

I created this post with shortcode and in my home template i used this :

```
[most_sold_items title="Most sold" category="most_sold" link="#" ]
```

and now i am unable use this link.

Though I'm kinda new to wordpress, so it would be very helpful for me if u would ans this in detail.

Comment: i think you get your answer from here http://codex.wordpress.org/Linking_Posts_Pages_and_Categories#Categories

Answer (score 0):

Find the category ID, then

```
<a href="index.php?cat=7">Category Title</a>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Linking_Posts_Pages_and_Categories#Categories

Comment: You would replace the "#" with "index.php?cat=7". 7 being the category ID, of course